# Are Oracle Cloud databases connections encrypted?

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a DB System in Oracle Cloud with a database.

I was wondering if connections directly to the database in the VM are encrypted. I know that connections to AWS RDS databases are encrypted.

I'm connected directly from SQL Developer to the database without SSH tunneling.

The database is inside a VM Machine and not an autonomous database.

Here is the connection string:

Easy connect connection string

```
someprefix.subXXXXXXXXXX.xxxxxxx.oraclevcn.com:1521/Some_Name.subXXXXXXXXXX.xxxxxxx.oraclevcn.com
```

Long connection string:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.85)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=Some_Name.subXXXXXXXXXX.xxxxxxx.oraclevcn.com)))
```

Comment: Yes, I think so: [How to connect to Oracle Autonomous Cloud Databases](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/how-to-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases): *To connect your applications to an Oracle Autonomous Cloud Database - any of the Oracle Autonomous Database services like Autonomous Data Warehouse (ADW), Autonomous Transaction Processing (ATP), or the new Oracle Autonomous JSON Database (AJD) - then you will need to download and use a 'wallet'. This gives mutual TLS which provides enhanced security for authentication and encryption.*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for your answer. As I have specified in my question, It's not an autonomous database. It's a database inside a DB System (VM).

Comment: What is the connection string?

Comment: By default, the sqlnet.ora for a DBCS requires encryption for client connections. So yes, they are encrypted if your leave that configuration in place.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I added the connection string. Thanks for your help

Comment: I would expect some `security=` and/or `wallet_location=` settings. I assume it is not encrypted in this case.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I checked the file sqlnet.ora. It has the following settings : `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=REQUIRED`, `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER=(AES256,AES192,AES128)`, `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT=REQUIRED`, `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT=(AES256,AES192,AES128)`. So I assume, it's encrypted. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I really don't know. I would expect an error, because you don't specify any encryption key. Perhaps the key is generated from your password hash value.

Comment: @ThomasCarlton you are correct: based on your sqlnet.ora settings, your connection should be encrypted. There aren't any parameters in the TNS connection string that would tell you for certain if native encryption is being used (only SSL) - sqlnet.ora parameters are the only thing. No explicit encryption key is required in sqlnet.ora; the encryption seed parameter was deprecated a long time ago. For a database on a VM (*not* Autonomous DB) like yours, a wallet would only be required if you were using SSL encryption; what you have is configured is native Oracle encryption.

Comment: If you want a positive test of the encryption, perform a client-side TNS trace or use a tool like WIreshark to confirm what's actually being sent over the wire.